# Writing lots of printf functions decreases the run time of the program

Tags: c, openmp

I have written a multi threading program in c using openmp. The program has around 400 parallelized functions calls. These functions have some printf functions to print some debug informations. I have observed that by removing these printf functions the run time of program increases from 1.2 secs to 1.6 secs. I am observing these phenomena consistently. How can this be possible?

Comment: Is the program even quicker still if you run it in single threaded mode?>

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, In single threaded mode the program takes around 25 secs, and hence there is not any observable difference.

Comment: Post the code.  The answer is likely specific to what you're doing.

Comment: What is the execution context? I've seen similar things happen when running on CPU's that support dynamic clock speed adjustment, because the extra work causes the CPU to kick into "performance" mode, which runs at a higher clock speed, resulting in a shorter wall clock time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the parallel function calls depend on each other in any way?  Since you are not likely running this across 400 cores, there will be some overhead in the context switches as various threads get scheduled.  It is possible that the printf results in yielding the CPU (while it writes to stdout), and by chance that it is a good place to yield the CPU (i.e. it is not at that point blocking any other thread).

I work on a multi-process application, that occasionally does synchronous writes to disk.  One thing I've seen is that getting rid of all the synchronous writes increases the speed of that process, but at the cost of the overall system not running as smoothly.  Instead we just ensure to avoid writing whilst holding any semaphore locks.

If processes are always pausing waiting for a synchronous write to finish, and if it isn't blocking anything else, everything gets a chance to run with very low latency, and the overall system is quite a bit faster.